# Check if Action is async lambda

Tags: c#, async-await

Since I can define an Action as

```
Action a = async () => { };
```

Can I somehow determine (at run time) whether the action a is async or not?

Comment: It what case would you not already know if it is or not?

Comment: @musefan when it's an input into a framework dll

Answer (score 18):

No - at least not sensibly. `async` is just a source code annotation to tell the C# compiler that you really want an asynchronous function/anonymous function.

You *could* fetch the `MethodInfo` for the delegate and check whether it has an appropriate attribute applied to it. I personally wouldn't though - the need to know is a design smell. In particular, consider what would happen if you refactored most of the code out of the lambda expression into another method, then used:

```
Action a = () => CallMethodAsync();
```

At that point you *don't* have an async lambda, but the semantics would be the same. Why would you want any code using the delegate to behave differently?

EDIT: This code appears to work, but I would *strongly recommend against it*:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsThisAsync(() => {}));       // False
        Console.WriteLine(IsThisAsync(async () => {})); // True
    }

    static bool IsThisAsync(Action action)
    {
        return action.Method.IsDefined(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute),
                                       false);
    }
}
```

Comment: My curiosity is getting the better of me. Why would you strongly recommend against it?

Comment: @DavidBožjak: My curiosity is getting the better of me.  Why would you want to use this code?

Comment: @Brian I'm writing a framework that takes Action as an input, but async Actions aren't supported. This is documented, but this way I get to throw an exception if the user passes an async Action anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, You can do that.

```
private static bool IsAsyncAppliedToDelegate(Delegate d)
{
    return d.Method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute)) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to build some logic, based on whether a `sync` or `async` lanbda has been passed to your method - just introduce *overloads*.

```
public void MyMethod(Action action)
{
    DoStuff();
}
public void MyMethod(Func<Task> asyncAction)
{
    DoOtherStuff();
}
```