# How to prevent an action parameter from being an async lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await

I am writing a small wrapper (`MyWrapper`) for use in unit tests. Its purpose is to wrap test code with a try-catch in order to catch one specific exception (`MySpecialException`) and then ignore the test.

*Why I do that should not be relevant for this question.*

**Given the code below**, how do I prevent others from passing an `Action` and using async like this?
Or in other words: How do I force them to use `MyWrapper.ExecuteAsync(Func<Task>)` instead?

---

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace PreventAsyncActionLambdaExample
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Example
    {
        [Test]
        public async Task ExampleTest()
        {
            // How do I prevent others from passing an action and using async like this?
            // Or in other words: How do I force them to use MyWrapper.ExecuteAsync(Func<Task>) instead?
            MyWrapper.Execute(async () =>
            {
                var cut = new ClassUnderTest();

                await cut.DoSomethingAsync();

                Assert.Fail("Problem: This line will never be reached");
            });
        }
    }

    public static class MyWrapper
    {
        // This method SHOULD NOT, BUT WILL be used in this example
        public static void Execute(Action action)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch (MySpecialException)
            {
            Assert.Ignore("Ignored due to MySpecialException");
            }
        }

        // This method SHOULD BE USED in this example, BUT WILL NOT be used.
        public static async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> func)
        {
            try
            {
                await func();
            }
            catch (MySpecialException)
            {
                Assert.Ignore("Ignored due to MySpecialException");
            }
        }
    }

    public class MySpecialException : Exception
    {
        // This is another exception in reality which is not relevant for this example
    }

    public class ClassUnderTest
    {
        public Task DoSomethingAsync()
        {
            return Task.Delay(20); // Simulate some work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an `async` method. That keyword is just syntactic sugar that allows the compiler to generate a state machine. The problem here is that the lambda is an `async void`, ie just a `void` method that can't be awaited.  It *is* just an Action as far as method resolution is concerned. If it was an `async Task` you wouldn't be able to use `Execute`

Comment: To put it another way, `async () => {}` like any `async void` can't be awaited, so it isn't possible to use `ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But that is what I am doing in other tests like so: `await MyWrapper.Execute(async () => {...}`

Comment: This means that you have another `Execute` method that returns a Task. You can't use `await` on ` public static void Execute(Action action)` because it doesn't return anything that can be awaited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that you can't really prevent this at compile-time but you could write another overload that will be picked-up in this case to tell them that they are supposed to use `ExecuteAsync` instead:

```
public static Task Execute(Func<Task> action)
{
    throw new Exception("Please use the ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> func) method instead if you will be passing async lambdas");
}
```

Comment: That signature is an `async void`, ie a `void` ie an Action. `Execute(Func<Task>)` won't be called because `Execute(Action)` matches the signature. Methods with `async void` can't be awaited anyway. Semantically, there is nothing wrong with the code - why call ExecuteAsync if the lambda can't be awaited?

Comment: Nope, I can not do this because then the compiler complains that "a method with that signature is already declared".

Comment: @ChrisM the compiler would only complain if an `Execute(Func<Task>)` method already existed. Your code though only shows `ExecuteAsync`. Have you defined another `Execute`? Remember `async` is just syntactic sugar so it doesn't affect overload resolution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right. I renamed the `ExecuteAsync` method to `Execute` earlier but did not tell this here. This way I at least get a warning that the call is not awaited.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, I do not think you can prevent it in compile time. However, you can do a hacky workaround and throw an exception. Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19024085/4949005). It might not be a good solution, but it could at least make the test fail.

```
public static bool IsThisAsync(Action action)
{
    return action.Method.IsDefined(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute),
        false);
}

// This method SHOULD NOT, BUT WILL be used in this example
public static void Execute(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        if (IsThisAsync(action))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is async");
            throw new ArgumentException("Action cannot be async.", nameof(action));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Is not async");
        }

        action();
    }
    catch (MySpecialException)
    {

    }
}
```

And tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyWrapperTests
{
    // Will not pass
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldAllowAsyncAction()
    {
        // This will throw an exception
        MyWrapper.Execute(async () =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Kind of async");
            });
        });
    }

    // Will pass, since ArgumentException is expected.
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void ShouldThrowArgumentExceptionWhenAsync()
    {
        // This will throw an exception. But that's expected.
        MyWrapper.Execute(async () =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Kind of async");
            });
        });
    }

    // Passes
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldAllowSyncAction()
    {
        MyWrapper.Execute(() =>
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        });
    }
}
```