# Disallow 'async' delegates from being passed as method argument

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

Let's say I have a method like this that takes an **Action** as an argument:

```
public void runAction(Action theAction)
{
    theAction();
}
```

How can I make sure that an 'async' delegate **cannot** be passed to the method? In other words, I want to **disallow** the following:

```
public void doStuff()
{
    runAction(async delegate ()
    {
        await doAsyncStuff();
    });
}
```

The reason I want to disallow 'async' delegates from being passed into the synchronous 'runAction' method is to keep silent bugs from occurring. For example, if there are two versions of 'runAction' (synchronous and asynchronous ones), and the user accidentally passes the async delegate into the synchronous one, the compiler nor the program will throw an error, but unintended consequences may occur.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024014/check-if-action-is-async-lambda) for a potential answer.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make sure that an `async` delegate cannot be passed to the method?

You can't, because an anonymous asynchronous function can be converted to a `void` delegate.

What you could do, however, is introduce an overload that accepts `Func<Task>`, which would be resolved if an `async` delegate was passed.

This would allow you handle asynchronous delegates differently:

```
public void RunAction(Action theAction)
{
    theAction();
}

public void RunAction(Func<Task> theAction)
{
    // do something different with an async delegate..
}
```

Whilst this will not prevent compile time errors, you could throw an exception or log the fact that the method was used incorrectly, rather than let it error silently.

Answer (score -1):

Timothy Stepanski's linked comment helped me to put a check in that throws an exception if it detects that the delegate is async:

[Check if Action is async lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024014/check-if-action-is-async-lambda)

```
public void runAction(Action theAction)
{
    var IsAsync = theAction.Method.IsDefined(typeof(AsyncStateMachineAttribute));
    theAction = IsAsync ? throw new Exception("async delegates are not allowed") : theAction;
    theAction();
}
```